# Better way to get where a request actually came from

Tags: php

I am aware that `$_SERVER[REFERRER]` can be used to detect where a request comes from however it turned out that it can be fooled or even a browser might not send it as part of the request.

Could anyone suggest a better way to detect or rather allow requests from own domain only to avoid spoofing, DoS, etc security attacks?

Comment: You want to make sure a request originated from your own website? Is that correct?

Comment: @LeviMorrison: Yes that's correct.

Comment: In regards to DoS, if your server gets to the point where it starts processing the script... mostly likely you are already suffering from the attack.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you are referring to [CSRF attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). First tutorial that I found is [this one](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/).

As @afuzzyllama pointed out, DoS consists of sending more data than your server/network connection can handle. In such a case, your PHP script will not be accessible anymore, so you can not implement a DoS protection in your PHP application. This must be done by your network administrator or hosting company.